# objective c : can't display UIImage from url http://image.ohozaa.com/i/3ca/inIHge.jpg

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

```
NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://image.ohozaa.com/i/3ca/inIHge.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

`image` return `nil`

But `UIImage` can display another url normally

Is it possible to set `UIImage` at this URL ?

Comment: I just ran your code and it works. `image` is not `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

The image takes more than a minute to load. Put the image on a faster server, or use a more reliable method to download the data. `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL` does not handle errors and won't allow you to configure timeouts. It is not recommended in general.

Instead, either roll your own with a NSURLConnection or try out AFNetworking ([on github](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)).

Comment: This is all good advice but none of it answers the question. Why is `image` coming out as `nil`?

Comment: You are feeding nil data to the image. If you init an image with nil, it will come back as nil. I suspect your call to dataWithContentsOfURL is timing out.

Comment: But the data isn't `nil`. Try it. It works just fine.